# SpriteKit Inelastic Collision Reducing Velocity

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody, sknode

I'm building a pong/breaker game with a ball and non-static blocks. I'd like the ball to never stop moving, but whenever it hits a block it loses velocity.

I have the restitusion = 1 for all sprites involved, I've tried setting the mass equal to each other and the density and the friction = 0. But, the ball still loses velocity on a bounce.

When the ball hits a block I'm removing it in the didBegin(contact:) function. I've also tried delaying the removal and it didn't help.

I'd like for the ball to have a constant velocity, but still be able to interact with the blocks as later I'd like to add blocks that can be hit without immediately being broken. So, the blocks can't be static but the ball needs to have a constant velocity.

My code for creating the ball node:

```swift
    func ballNode(_ position: CGPoint?) -> SKSpriteNode {
        let node = SKSpriteNode()
        node.position = position == nil ? CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: 100) : position!
        node.size = CGSize(width: 17, height: 17)

        //background
        let background = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 8.5)
        background.fillColor = UIColor.white

        node.addChild(background)

        //physics
        node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 8.5)
        node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        node.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        node.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        node.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        node.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

        node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BallCategory
        node.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = AddBlockBorderCategory | PaddleCategory
        node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PaddleCategory | BlockCategory | BorderCategory

        return node
    }
```

My code for creating the block node:

```swift
    func createBlockNode() -> BlockNode {
        let width = (size.width-CGFloat(6*layout[0].count))/CGFloat(layout[0].count)
        let height = width*0.5
        let nodeSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        let node = BlockNode(texture: nil, size: nodeSize)

        let background = SKShapeNode(rectOf: nodeSize)
        background.fillColor = .darkGray
        background.strokeColor = .lightGray

        //physics
        node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: nodeSize)
        node.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        node.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BlockCategory
        node.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BallCategory

        node.addChild(background)
        return node
    }
```

And a screen recording:
[screen recording of the ball losing velocity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bALMT.jpg)

I'm starting the ball using this:

```swift
ball!.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50))
```

Comment: If you want some specific mechanic for your ball like a fix the velocity you can set each time or check often. With the actual velocity vector, you can normalize and apply the right velocity each time.

Comment: Ah that worked! In the update loop I just found the ratio of the current velocity and the wanted velocity and  set the new velocity to be the correct one. Thank you!